# Custom form field not working on server

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, custom-field

I created a custom component and in the form one custom field `categoryList` to list all categories dynamically. Following is the code:

1. **formname.xml**

   ```
   <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_componentname/models/fields">
    <field name="id" type="text" readonly="true" class="readonly" default="0" description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_DESC"/>

    <field name="cat_id_01" type="categoryList" onchange="loadSubcategory(1)" label="Category 1" description="Category">
       <option value="">Please select</option>
    </field>
   </fieldset>
   ```
2. **edit.php**

   ```
   <?php echo $this->form->renderField('cat_id_01'); ?>
   ```
3. **How it appears on localhost:** it displays as select-box with category options. This is how I want it to be displayed. `php version: 7.0.0`
4. **models/fields/categoryList.php**

   ```
       JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

               /**
                * Supports an HTML select list of categories
                *
                * @since  1.6
                */
               class JFormFieldCategoryList extends JFormFieldList
               {
                   /**
                    * The form field type.
                    *
                    * @var        string
                    * @since    1.6
                    */
                   protected $type = 'categoryList';

                   /**
                    * Method to get the field input markup.
                    *
                    * @return    string    The field input markup.
                    *
                    * @since    1.6
                    */
                   public function getOptions()
                   {
                       $categories[NULL] = 'Please Select';
                       $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                       $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                       $query = 'SELECT id, title FROM `#__categories` WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id from `#__categories` where title="'.$jinput->get('section').'")';
                       $rows = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectlist();
                       foreach ($rows as $row) {
                           $categories[$row->id] = $row->title;
                       }

                       return $categories;
                   }

               }
   ```
5. **How it appears on server:** it displays as textbox and somehow the custom field is not working on server. `php version: 7.0.17`

   ```
   <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" name="jform[cat_id_01]" id="jform_cat_id_01" value="110" list="jform_cat_id_01_datalist" onchange="loadSubcategory(1)"><datalist id="jform_cat_id_01_datalist"></datalist>
   </div>
   ```
6. **Joomla version:** 3.6.5

I want to display the field as selectbox on server as well.

Comment: On some reason it doesn't see the either the XML file at the server or categoryList.php at the server. You get a regular textbox instead of your field if Joomla doesn't see the field php file.

Maybe you forgot to upload somethig or there is a path problem (windows/linux).

There is a chance there is a PHP error. Set error level to Developemnt in Global configuration to see if there is some usefull information. If not done yet.

Comment: @Gruz that's right. It was not reading the `categoryList.php` file. The issue was with the camelcase naming convention. When I changed it to `categorylist.php` it worked on server. Maybe some sort of setting was there

Answer (score 1):

[This page appears abandoned, so I'll transfer the commented solution as an answer.]

As described in the comments, the issue was with the camelcasing in the filename. For Joomla to access the file, the filename must be in lowercase:

**models/fields/categoryList.php** should be **models/fields/categorylist.php**

---

Additionally, I'll offer a revised `getOptions()` function declaration with Joomla query building syntax to replace the raw sql string and do my best to implement [Joomla's php coding standards](https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/php-code.html).

```
public function getOptions()
{
    $section = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->get("section");
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $subquery = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName("id"))
        ->from($db->quoteName("#__categories"))
        ->where($db->quoteName("title") . " = " . $db->quote($section));

    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName(["id", "title"]))
        ->from($db->quoteName("#__categories"))
        ->where($db->quoteName("parent_id") . " IN (" . $subquery . ")");

    $rows = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectlist();
    $categories[null] = 'Please Select';
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $categories[$row->id] = $row->title;
    }
    return $categories;
}
```