# SQL syntax error in query with subquery using JDatabase

Tags: jdatabase, joomla-4

I'm coding my first Joomla! 4 component. There are two tables for the component: *pfx_list*, and *pfx_member_to_list*. Table *pfx_list* hash primary key *id*, and table *pfx_member_to_list* has foreign key *list_id* pointing to table *pfx_list*.

I need a list of all rows of *pfx_list* joined with the number of matches in *pfx_member_to_list*, which can be none, one, or many.

In the first version, there was a simple LEFT JOIN, but this did (of course) not return rows with zero entries in the right table. *But*, this version was running fine (except for the missing rows), so I know the component code is basically ok.

I then changed the query to a LEFT JOIN on a subselect, so that rows with no matches in the right table will also be returned. This is the query, and when run through php_myadmin, it returns the desired result:

```
SELECT a.id, a.list_name, coalesce( member_cnt, 0 )
FROM      pfx_list as a
LEFT JOIN ( select list_id, count(*) as member_cnt 
            from pfx_member_to_list
            group by list_id
            ) b
        ON a.id = b.list_id
GROUP BY a.list_name
ORDER BY a.list_name;
```

I'm stuck with translating this to a JDataBase query object. Here is the current code:

```
$db       = $this->getDbo();
$query    = $db->getQuery(true);
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true);

$subquery->select(['list_id', 'count(*) as member_cnt'])
         ->from($db->quotename('#__member_to_list', 'b'))
         ->group($db->quotename('b.list_id'));

$query->select(['a.id', 'a.list_name', 'a.nz_list_id', 'a.nz_list_key', 'coalesce(member_cnt, 0)'])
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__list', 'a'))
      ->join('LEFT', $subquery . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.list_id'))
      ->order($db->quoteName('a.list_name') . ' ASC')
      ->group($db->quotename('a.list_name'));
```

When the query is run in Joomla! via admin menu entry, I'm getting error:

```
An error has occurred.
500 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT list_id,count(*) as member_cnt FROM 
`pfx_member_to_...' at line 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT list_id,count(*) as 
member_cnt FROM ``pfx_member_to_...' at line 4
```

I've tried removing `quoteName()`, and some more changes, but cannot seem to find out what is wrong.

**Edit 1**: Here is a [working sample on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ssXoXNNop6oa3zmVuswRNY/2)

Comment: Related posts I've made with subqueries: [1](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24201/12352), [2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/26730/12352), [3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24148/12352), [4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24161/12352), [5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24180/12352), [6](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28411/12352), [7](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23899/12352), [8](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22916/12352).  I recommend `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');` to see your rendered sql (not in production code).

Comment: Specific to JOINing subqueries, here is an answer showing how to make three separate subquery JOINs: [How to SET a user-defined MySQL variable and increment it to produce ranking values with JDatabaseQuery?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22916/12352)

Comment: Can you please provide a db-fiddle.com demo with a small set of sample data for us? I am not convinced that you actually need to JOIN on a subquery.

Comment: @mickmackusa First time using db-fiddle.com. Hope the link I added above is what you've requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actual fetch the desired result without implementing a JOIN on a subquery.

Use a LEFT JOIN if you want the possibility of zero counts in the results.  Use a regular JOIN (INNER JOIN) if you want to exclude zero counts from your result set.

If your `name` column is guaranteed to be unique, you can GROUP BY that column.  If you might possibly have shared `name` values in the first table, then you'll need to GROUP BY something that will be unique -- like the `id` column for absolute stability -- as well as the `name` column that you want in your SELECT clause.

SQL: ([Generalised DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4MD26vqrq51wAYK1NXmXMW/1))

```
SELECT a.id, a.list_name, COUNT(b.id) 
FROM pfx_list AS a
LEFT JOIN pfx_member_to_list AS b ON a.id = b.list_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.list_name
ORDER BY a.list_name
```

Joomla Query Builder Syntax:

```
$query->select("a.id, a.list_name, COUNT(b.id) AS cnt")
   ->from("#__list AS a"))
   ->join("LEFT", "#__member_to_list AS b ON a.id = b.list_id")
   ->group("a.id, a.list_name")
   ->order("a.list_name");
```

---

EDIT: With your newly supplied db-fiddle, I have adjust the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses to include your extra columns.  No subquery is needed. ([DB-Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ssXoXNNop6oa3zmVuswRNY/4))

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.list_name,
       a.nz_list_id,
       a.nz_list_key,
       COUNT(b.member_id) cnt
FROM lists AS a
LEFT JOIN member_to_list AS b ON a.id = b.list_id
GROUP BY a.id,
         a.list_name,
         a.nz_list_id,
         a.nz_list_key
ORDER BY a.list_name
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what my first non-subquery looked like. Just didn't think of counting on the unique id of the second table. From a performance point of view, which one is th better solution?

Comment: I expect that avoiding the subquery will be more performant, but I'll make no guarantees.  I'll leave it to you to test performance using your real project data and real table schema / column indexes.  Makes sure to turn off query caching in PHPMyAdmin when you benchmark test. [Testing performance of queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2756100/2943403)

Answer (score 4):

1. to spot a sql syntax error it's useful to view the resultant sql eg.

   ```
    echo $query->__toString();
   ```
2. you've put the alias of the subquery 'b' as the alias of the table inside the subquery.  But the main reason is that the subquery needs parentheses in the join clause.

   ```
    $subquery->select(['list_id', 'count(*) as member_cnt'])
         ->from($db->quotename('#__member_to_list'))
         ->group($db->quotename('b.list_id'));

    $query->select(['a.id', 'a.list_name', 'a.nz_list_id', 'a.nz_list_key', 'coalesce(member_cnt, 0)'])
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__list', 'a'))
      ->join('LEFT', '(' . $subquery . ') AS b ON ' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.list_id'))
      ->order($db->quoteName('a.list_name') . ' ASC')
      ->group($db->quotename('a.list_name'));
   ```

Comment: Thanks. There were still two errors in your answer. Firtsly, in the subquery, it has to say `group($db->quotename('list_id'))`instead of `...('b.list_id'))`. Secondly, in the query I had to name the count column, i.e. `coalesce(b.member_cnt, 0) as member_cnt`.